# Python JSON data dump with mulitple values

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I’m new to Python. I've managed to put together a script that scrapes a webpage (example of the response below) and then dumps the data in JSON format to a file.

There are several Item elements in the response and I want objects from each of them. This is working well and each json object in the file has a guid and a title. However there are several category elements in each Item and I can’t figure out how to add these to the output. I can iterate through the category elements and print them but can’t then append them to output.

The response I get is of the following structure:

```
<channel>
    <title>XXX</title>
    ...
    <item>
        <title>XX</title>
        <description>XX</description>
        <category>AAA</category>
        ...
        <category>DDD</category>
        <guid>XX</guid>
    </item>
        ...
    <item>
        …
    </item>
    …
</channel>
```

This is the the code:

```
import urllib
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

webPage = urllib.urlopen('XXX')
soup = BeautifulSoup(webPage.read())

items = soup.find_all('item')
output = []

for item in items:  
    for c in item.findAll('category'):
        print c # each category prints out but how to add this to output?
    output.append({
    "guid":  (item.find("guid").contents[0]).encode('utf-8'),
    "title": (item.find("title").contents[0]).encode('utf-8'),

    #"category":  item.findAll('category')
    })

with open("jsonOutput.json", 'w') as jsonFile:
    json.dump(output, jsonFile, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii=False)
jsonFile.close()
```

thanks so much for looking!!!

Comment: Can you share the actual output and the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My beautifulsoup knowledge can be a bit rusty.

You want to append a category node that contains a list of strings, like:

```
"guid": ["category_1","category_2",...,"category_n"]
```

This can be done in a way like:

```
for item in items:
    categories = [c.contents[0].encode('utf-8') for c in item.findAll('category')]
    output.append({
    "guid":  (item.find("guid").contents[0]).encode('utf-8'),
    "title": (item.find("title").contents[0]).encode('utf-8'),
    "category": categories,
    })
```

which will output:

```
[
    {
        "category": [
            "AAA", 
            "DDD"
        ], 
        "guid": "XX", 
        "title": "XX"
    }
]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, that's exactly what I needed! :-)

Comment: Good to know! Just for your information, the line `categories = [c.contents[0].encode('utf-8') for c in item.findAll('category')]` is called a list comprehension. It's an awesome and compact way to build up lists! Goodluck!